# How to compile .class files

Tags: java, eclipse, .class-file

I am new to Java, I have some *.class files which needs to be modified. Now I de-compiled these *.class files to get the source code using the famous [JD Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/). The concern is after I change the code and  need to recompile these *.class files how will I do it with Eclipse. I only the compiled *.class files.

I know its a stupid question but bear with me I'm .NET Developer with a few days into Java.

Comment: If you have the decompiled files than you have the java source. You have to create a new project with these files. The eclipse will compile then to you.

Comment: I think he wants to know where Eclipse puts the .class files.  Typically, that's in the /bin directory under the project you've opened in Eclipse, but might be in another location depending on how your project is built.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not compile a `*.class` file, Its already compiled code (bytecode) for its `*.java` source.
I think you need to copy the code from JD Decompiler's editor to a java source file.

i.e. copy the source code from JD's editor for `Hello.class` into a file named `Hello.java`.
Now you can move this file in IDE of your choice or directly compile using javac.
(dont forget to put all the dependencies/required jars/source in project build path)

Answer (score 3):

I think that you can use javac.

For example, if you have three `.java` files:

> source1.java
>   directory\source2.java
>   directory\directory2\source3.java

Execute:

```
javac source1.java directory\source2.java package\package2\source3.java
```

And you can create a file.jar with all .class:

```
jar cf file.jar source1.class directory\source2.class directory\directory2\source3.class
```